# Keyframing a pose asset in Python

Tags: python, scripting, pose-mode, actions, asset-browser

I want to apply and keyframe a pose asset. The first part of applying a pose was described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/255415/154884). However, I am not sure how to keyframe the action.

This is my code:

```
def apply_pose(frame, pose):
    win = bpy.context.window
    scr = win.screen
    area = scr.areas[0]
    area.type = "DOPESHEET_EDITOR"e

    with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
        bpy.data.objects['DeOne'].animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions[pose]
        for i in bpy.context.selected_objects[0].data.bones:
             i.select = True

        bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="WholeCharacter")
```

I also tried `bpy.ops.action.keyframe_insert()` and `bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="BUILTIN_KSI_BendyBones")`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a coder but use it for speech animation quite a bit.
Have you tried the last line:
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')
it works in most instances for me.